# React Router DOM's Router doesn't accept history correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been trying to create a utility function that wraps React Testing Library's `render` function that uses `Router` to wrap the whole React Element. The code looks like this.

```js
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { render as renderRTL } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createMemoryHistory, History } from 'history';

export function render(ui: ReactElement) {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  return {
    history,
    ...renderRTL(<Router history={history}>{ui}</Router>),
  };
}
```

The problem here is I keep on getting an error message from TypeScript saying that `History<State> is not assignable to History<unknown>` on this line of the code.

```js
...renderRTL(<Router history={history}>{ui}</Router>),
```

This is the full error message.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: RouterProps | Readonly<RouterProps>): Router', gave the following error.
    Type 'History<State>' is missing the following properties from type 'History<unknown>': length, goBack, goForward
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouterProps, context: any): Router', gave the following error.
    Type 'History<State>' is not assignable to type 'History<unknown>'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(105, 5): The expected type comes from property 'history' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Router> & Readonly<RouterProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
index.d.ts(105, 5): The expected type comes from property 'history' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Router> & Readonly<RouterProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
```

And this is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "TITLE",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.21",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.6",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.8",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "autoprefixer": "9",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "husky": "^5.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "postcss": "7",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx src",
    "format": "prettier --write \"./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\"",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css}": [
      "npm run format"
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem should be the missing `length`, `goBack`, and `goForward` properties from the memory history.

Is it a bug with `react-router` itself?

Comment: I just copy & pasted the code into a fresh app and I'm not seeing any error.  I'll play with your package.json and see if the problem lies there.

Comment: Thanks, maybe there is something wrong with my packages. I'm assuming incompatible version of `react-router-dom` and `history`

Comment: Looks like it works fine a CodeSandbox with your package.json: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-ptolemy-e9llu?file=/src/App.tsx  Try closing your IDE, restarting, and reopening?  No idea what's going wrong but this shouldn't be an error.

Comment: Let me check your code on CodeSandbox

Comment: Also you can uninstall `history` and `react-router` and let `react-router-dom` install the correct versions on its own.

Comment: I think it works on CodeSandbox as its not doing TypeScript checks on the fly. I'll try uninstalling `history` and `react-router` for the moment

Comment: Looks like it's OK in TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wOaxdm

Comment: Thanks, it's actually working fine. Looks like I did accidentally install `history` as dev-dependencies, which causes the types to be incompatible. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Great!  You should write up a quick answer in case anyone else has this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally installed `history` as a dev-dependency, which is causing the types to be incompatible. To resolve this, I remove `history` and re-install `react-router-dom` to make sure it's properly installed. Here's how to do it using `pnpm`

```
pnpm remove history
pnpm add react-router-dom
```

Comment: Just heads up, eslint will yell: `'history' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S history' to add it`. Unfortunately, beside disabling eslint for this line I couldn't find a solution.